# Android: Database backup issue

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-backups

In my application I have an option to export the database file to sdcard. Exporting is working fine and the problem is, (to put it clear) for example

- I took a backup of the database file containing some data.
- After that I have modified some data in my application.
- When I try to import the saved backup file, the changes what I did in my application(after exporting the database file) are being modified in this backup file too.

I'm kind of confused with this weird behavior. I think the backup database file and internal app database has a link and whatever I modify in my application is being reflected in the backup file.

If anyone know why and how to overcome this, please suggest. Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: some code would be helpful...

Comment: @Goddchen Code is very huge, cant post it here. And I'm not importing the complete backup file as it is, but I'm reading the content in the tables inside the backup file and adding them to the internal database. Importantly I just want to know whether there is any link between the backup file and internal database? If yes, then how can I solve it? Thanks.